# Grouping lists by elements in Netlogo

Tags: list, foreach, netlogo

Let us say I have a model in Netlogo and am now interested in developing a reporter/procedure that groups lists according to their first element.
For the sake of example, let's say

```
globals[list1 list2 list3 listoflists
ordered-list-a
  ordered-list-b
]

to setup
  set list1 ["a" "b" "c"]
  set list2 ["a" "c" "d"]
  set list3 ["b" "a" "c"]
  set listoflists (list list1 list2 list3)
end
```

I want to create a list of lists such that in each list you have lists starting with the same element. Hence, the desired output is

```
[[["a" "b" "c"]["a" "c" "d"]]["b" "a" "c"]]]
```

i.e, where the first element aggregates all lists with an a in first place, and the second all those starting with a "b".

Ideally, this should be scalable for a large number. I tried

```
to create-list
  set ordered-list-a []
  set ordered-list-b []
   (foreach listoflists [[i] ->
    if item 0 i = "a" [set ordered-list-a lput i ordered-list-a]
  if item 0 i = "b" [set ordered-list-b lput i ordered-list-b]
  ])  
end
```

and then creating a list from a and b, which does the trick, but a) it's incredibly messy, b) requires that I know beforehand the length of the list, which I don't in the real case (it's a turtle procedure) and c) it seems like a lot of unnecessary coding.

Is there some way to extend the procedure above to any number of starting elements (maybe inside a while cycle?) and does not require the creation of a list for each initial list element?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming the desired output is supposed to be: `[[["a" "b" "c"]["a" "c" "d"]][["b" "a" "c"]]]`. I believe you were missing a `[` before the second group.

Anyway, a simple, but somewhat inefficient way would be:

```
; items is a list of items to be grouped
; key is an anonymous reporter that extracts the group label from a single item
to-report group-by [ items key ]
  let keys remove-duplicates map key items
  report map [ k -> filter [ x -> (runresult key x) = k ] items ] keys
end
```

Note that the above is a completely generalized grouping function. To use it in your case, you would do:

```
group-by listoflists [ l -> first l ]
```

A more efficient way would be to use the [table:group-items reporter from the table extension](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/table.html#table:group-items).

```
table:group-items listoflists [ l -> first l ]
```

Comment: Great! Many thanks, Bryan. Will use the table extension to minimize code (need to do this for several agent types...) works like a charm! :-)

Comment: And yes, indeed I was missing a square bracket, well spotted.